# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS runs very much slower than 9.04

Tags: 12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and it really runs too slow, a lot slower than my previously used 9.04 Jaunty .

My system specs :

32 bit
767 MB RAM
CPU = AMD Athlon, 1050 MHz

Motherboard clock = 33 MHz

Besides that there is a problem with the terminal window : It gets transparent or whitened out much .

Am I missing some updates for these errors ?

Answer (score 1):

The joy of Unity (Gnome3). You may find it runs better with a lighter desktop environment like XFCE which can be installed by typing: sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop